# Why can't C# member names be the same as the enclosing type name?

Tags: c#, language-design

In C#, the following code doesn't compile:

```
class Foo {

    public string Foo;

}
```

The question is: why?

More exactly, I understand that this doesn't compile because (I quote):

> member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Ok, fine. I understand that, I won't do it again, I promise.

But I really don't understand *why* the compiler refuses to take any field having the same name as an enclosing type. What is the underlying issue that prevents me to do that?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this is a limitation imposed by C#, most likely for convenience of syntax.  A constructor has a method body, but its member entry in IL is denoted as ".ctor" and it has slightly different metadata than a normal method (In the Reflection classes, ConstructorInfo derives from MethodBase, not MethodInfo.)  I don't believe there's a .NET limitation that prevents creating a member (or even a method) with the same name as the outer type, though I haven't tried it.

---

I was curious, so I confirmed it's not a .NET limitation.  Create the following class in VB:

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Sub Class1()

    End Sub
End Class
```

In C#, you reference it as:

```
var class1 = new Class1();
class1.Class1();
```

Comment: This is probably the best, most complete answer here.  In VB (I think I just threw up a little in my mouth) the ctor is Sub New ()...

Comment: Do you mean "prevents creating a member" the way he describes it in the question? Yeah, that's the whole reason for this question. If you mean like `public string Foo {get;set;} public void Foo(){}` then no that's not allowed either.

Comment: The question is if just C# disallows it or if the .net typesystem disallows it. And I'd guess it's just C#.

Comment: @Dave, VB.NET isn't so bad; I happen to be maintaining legacy VB6 code at the moment. :)

Comment: @Thomas, I agree, James covered that better.  C# followed the C++ example of using the class name for the constructor, so it was easiest simply to reserve that name for the class constructor.

Answer (score 21):

Because Foo is reserved as the name of the constructor.

So if your code was allowed - what would you call the constructor?

Even if it was possible to do this by treating the constructor as a special case and introducing new rules into method / member binding - would it be a good idea?  It would inevitably lead to confusion at some point.

Comment: But the constructor isn't a method or anything, it shouldn't interfere with the rest of the code.

Comment: The constructor is a method.  Why do you think it is not?  E.g. you can call it from a constructor in a derived object.

Comment: @James Gaunt, because it doesn't return anything, it's a [constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29). I'm not sure on how it works in C#, but in java a constructor has nothing to do with a method except that it's a block of code. Don't you call it with `base()` ? So it shouldn't be a problem here too.

Comment: @Colin Hebert ... I don't think you can have a member variable and a function have the same name... I'm pretty sure that's against the spec. So since the name of the class is the name of the constructor, then you can't use it for the name of a member variable. We're not discussing if a constructor is a method or a variable, but we're discussing what can be named what. Once you've declared a class, then the constructor name becomes reserved.

Comment: "Constructors are class methods that are executed when an object of a given type is created." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx

Comment: In the generated CIL, the constructor doesn't keep the type name. It is called `.ctor()`. So, once compiled, they are absolutely no conflict between `Foo`, which is the attribute, and the constructor, which is `.ctor`.

Comment: I don't think the name of the constructor is the same as the name of the class. That's just the C# syntax for declaring a constructor. The real name is something like `.ctor`. And an interesting question is if this naming restriction is just a C# language restriction or a real restriction of the .net type system.

Comment: "So if your code was allowed - what would you call the constructor?" I'd call it `this` such as `this('default', 'parameters');`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the member name clashes with the name of the class's constructor?

Comment: Yet this is fine in other languages

Answer (score -2):

There is a right way to do it and a wrong way to do it.

Why Doesn't C# allow it?

Because it does not reason to do so. Why would you want to create such confusion in your life.

I think the CLR allows it, as another post proves with a vb.net example and it should not be restricted, but I would not want to create an application based on the same rules that the CLR operates in. The abstraction makes code more clear. I think the argument works on the same level as multiple inheritance. Yes it can be done in some languages, but it causes confusion. My answer therefore would be to reduce ambiguity and confusion and is based in the c# parser/compiler. A design choice by the C# team.