# Why does Entity Framework insist on renaming columns?

Tags: entity-framework

Step 1: import code first from existing database. Existing database has a table with the same name as column.

Step 2: in this scenario, Entity Framework sticks a "1" in front of column name in code.

Step 3: when I try to rename it "by getting rid of 1 in front", I get error

> member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Why is this limitation on EF and is there a solution that doesn't ruin the database in future migrations (by having that column renamed)?

Being forced to use `Column1` just seems really terrible and arbitrary.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why C# member names can't be the same as the enclosing type name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074055/why-c-sharp-member-names-cant-be-the-same-as-the-enclosing-type-name)

Comment: Is this the primary key column? The pk column normally is called "Id" by entity framework convention or  table name + "Id", so it would be "ExampleId" if your table is called "Example".

Comment: @Martin Not a primary key, I was just wondering if i'm stuck calling it "Column1". Didn't realize this is a C# limitation and not entity framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @shf301 you cant have a property named the same as the class its in, this is a .NET restriction.

However you can name your column anything else and then tell EF to point to your specific column in the database

eg:

```
[Column("MyColumn")] // "MyColumn" will be what EF expects in the db
public int FlyingMonkies {get;set;}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid EF was going to rename it on migration and I'm at work so no time to test until I get home.